# how does one block a domain on api gateway

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I was just wondering if there is any way to toggle/turn off/disable/block an api gateway request from a particular domain. I need to test if the service is ever down to see if the error messaging is working

In chrome I can block the request in the network console, however, I can not do this in IE. is there a way to turn the api off temporarily?
or can i block it in IE?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this working with IP rather than the domain.

API gateway allows you to attach "Resource Policy" to your API

Example below

The following example resource policy is a "blacklist" policy that denies (blocks) incoming traffic to an API from two specified source IP addresses.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/*"]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/*"],
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": ["10.24.34.0/23",
                "10.24.34.0/24"]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

More Info
[API Gateway Resource Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html)
[API Gateway Resource Policy Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html)